# Unable to load FFMpeg in file in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, audio, ffmpeg

i'm trying to convert a varity of audio files into a specific audio type of my chossing on my laravel project.
on my search i landed on a package called Laravel FFMpeg, i started with a fresh installation with laravel 6.2, and did the installation as it shows on github, as soon as i started using it i had this error :

> FFMpeg\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException: Unable to load FFMpeg in file C:\Users\Hatim\Desktop\Projects\Audio\vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\Driver\FFMpegDriver.php on line 55
> #0 C:\Users\Hatim\Desktop\Projects\Audio\vendor\pbmedia\laravel-ffmpeg\src\Support\ServiceProvider.php(61): FFMpeg\Driver\FFMpegDriver::create(Object(Illuminate\Log\LogManager), Object(Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Configuration))

I'm currently just working with a simple thing :

```
FFMpeg::fromDisk('s3');
```

and yes I have called it my Controller: `use ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\FFMpeg;`

I have also tried to install the `PHP-FFMpeg` Package and also tried to install FFmpeg on my device and link it using the path in my config\laravel-FFmpeg

This is how it looks now without any modification, I went to my .env folder but it has nothing regarding FFmpeg so it takes the default value, that's why I tried installing it on my device and replacing the default value with the path of the FFmpeg on my device.

```
return [
'ffmpeg' => [
    'binaries' => env('FFMPEG_BINARIES', 'ffmpeg'),
    'threads'  => 12,
],

'ffprobe' => [
    'binaries' => env('FFPROBE_BINARIES', 'ffprobe'),
],

'timeout' => 3600,
'enable_logging' => true
```

];

I'm currently working on my local environment, but this has to work on a server.

Comment: In laravel 7-   The namespace has changed to `ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg`, the facade has been renamed to `ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\FFMpeg`,  
 https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg#upgrading-to-v7 this is for 6.x https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg/tree/laravel-6.0

Comment: I'm not planning to migrate to laravel 7 at the moment,  thanks for your comment but it did not solve my problem yet.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved the problem, this response is for future developers having a problem with the package.

first of all you have to install FFmpeg on your device, [click me][1]

chose your os and download it, unzip it rename it to FFmpeg, and then copy the folder and place it in your c: folder for example.

after that just go to your config\laravel-FFmpeg file in your project and change the defaults to the exact path in c: folder

```
'ffmpeg' => [
    'binaries' => env('FFMPEG_BINARIES', 'C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe'),
    'threads'  => 12,
],
'ffprobe' => [
    'binaries' => env('FFPROBE_BINARIES', 'C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe'),
],
```

Comment: in winodows OS use this C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe not C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe or use doube \\

Comment: How about in Ubuntu system? Downloaded the package from their Git repo, did ./configure and that installed the required dependencies. Now what's the bath that needs to be updated  under binaries? The downloaded/installed package is available at /home/hs/downloads/ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

Like a suggestions: set in your local .env file:

```
FFMPEG_BINARIES=C:\bin\ffmpeg.exe
FFPROBE_BINARIES=C:\bin\ffprobe.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case this worked as well

```
FFMPEG_PATH=c:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe

FFPROBE_PATH=c:/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, it's important to first verify the installation locations of ffmpeg and ffprobe. To do this, use the commands:

```
which ffmpeg
which ffprobe
```

In the Zsh shell, these commands might return paths such as:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg
```

and

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/ffprobe
```

Following this, you should update your `.env` file by adding the following environment variables:

```
FFMPEG_BINARIES=/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg
FFPROBE_BINARIES=/opt/homebrew/bin/ffprobe
```

This approach worked for me and should help in ensuring your applications correctly identify and use ffmpeg and ffprobe binaries on macOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).